# didSelectRowAtIndex isn't updating properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a TableView where I have Rows whose title holds the name of a property.

The Properties are defined on an other TableView where I can press "Add" to add the newly created Object to the First TableView.

If I now want to edit let's say the second Object in the list, I have to press it (switching to the second TableView) press Cancel and press it again, to get the correct name.

Something with the `didSelectRowAtIndex` doesn't seem to work right, but I can't figure out what it is.

Here's my method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.indexPathInt = (int)indexPath.row;
}
```

and:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:kSegueIdentifier]){

        AddEntry *controller = [[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

        controller.delegate = self;
    }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:kEditSegueIdentifier]) {

        edited = YES;

        AddEntry *controller = [[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

        EntryObject *entry = self.entryObjectArray[self.indexPathInt];

        controller.name = entry.name;
        controller.someProperty = entry.soneProperty;


        controller.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

If I log the `indexPathInt` in the `PrepareforSegue` method it's not the same as the `indexPath.row` in the `DidSelectRowAtIndex` method, but the one I clicked before.

So the `indexPathInt` does not get updated in time.

Is there another way to access the selected row in any method without sending it to an variable?

Comment: The `UITableView` method `indexPathForSelectedRow` will give you the `NSIndexPath` for the currently selected row.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling [self performSegueWithIdentifier...] before setting the self.indexPathInt.

If you are performing segue through the Storyboard, exactly what are you explaining will happen. Switch to programmatically calling the [self performSegueWithIdentifier] AFTER you set self.indexPathInt

Cheers.

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but how do I set self.indexPathInt before calling the segue?

Answer (score 0):

If you segue directly from the row instead manually from the viewController, prepareForSegue will get called before didSelectRowAtIndex path.

Edit:

- Drag your segue from the ViewController to your target, NOT from the ROW.
- Name the segue as you'd usually would
- Set the variable you want to set in didSelectRowAtIndexPath
- Call in didSelectRowAtIndexPath AFTER setting the variable:

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifierString" sender:self];

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but how do I set self.indexPathInt before calling the segue?